# What does *(int*)&variable means?

Tags: c, pointers, casting

I am generating arrays which are dynamic size. The part of the code that I am showing is grabbing value of the array the way it does, and it works.

The problem is I have no idea how this work. I don't see why both cast and pre-cast have pointer in it?

How to code something similar correctly?

Example: `*(double*)&j;`

I also noticed that `*(int*)&column_sum[i] + 1;` won't add the 1 to the result. Also I have no idea why...

```
    double val = 1000 * multiplier;
    double *column_sum = malloc(val * sizeof *column_sum);
    double *p = malloc(val * val * sizeof *p);
    printf("Rows/Columns: %.0f", val);

    for (i = 0; i < val; i++){
        column_sum[i] = 0.0;
        for (j = 0; j < val; j++){
            int index = i * (int)val + j;
            p[index] = *(double*)&j; // here
            int offsetI = *(int*)&column_sum[i] + 1; // here
            int offsetJ = *(int*)&p[index] + 1; // here
            printf("%d->", offsetI);
            printf("%d,", offsetJ);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
```

Comment: Maybe it's a stupid question, but how did you achieve coding something you do not understand?

Comment: lol http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinite_monkey_theorem lot of free time and googling maybe? i don't remember

Comment: It seems like you only want to use `int` type. And so there is lot of unnecessary casting taking place.

Comment: Why you didn't include the declaration of either your index vars (`i`, and `j`) when one of them is directly related to your question escapes me. Regardless, unless `sizeof(j)` is *at least* `sizeof(double)` **and** is properly conforming to the requirements of floating point alignment on your platform, this code has "this is an example of what **not** to do" written all over it. (and honestly, even if those conditions are true, that statement is still true).

Comment: This is only part of the code, every counter is INT type.

Comment: I suspected as such (about the index vars being `int`). This code is easily as hideous, if not more so, than my prior comment described it. The code is essentially saying "Take the address of this variable which is **not** a `double`, and have it assume the alias as a pointer-to-`double`, then dereference it and extract the value." (which will not work on any platform where `double` is not the same size as `int`, and even where it is you run the risk of alignment woes, as floating point tends to be rather finicky about that).

Comment: and yes, I was trying to avoid 'pointer-to-object'.

Comment: The comments remind me of the Kernighan quote: "Everyone knows that debugging is twice as hard as writing a program in the first place. So if you're as clever as you can be when you write it, how will you ever debug it?"

Comment: @HelpNeeder some counters are `size_t`, it's actually better to have them as such (in most cases) rather then `int`

Comment: Has anyone mentioned yet that you need to turn off most compiler optimizations in order to build working programs with code like that?

Comment: If the compiler optimizes it is free to use the "aliasing" rule which is that a program never accesses memory objects through pointers of different types (except for some uses of char*).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What does it do:

```
&var // get the pointer of the variable
(type*)&var // cast the pointer to an other pointer type
*(type*)&var // Dereferencing the casted pointer so "interpret" the variable as a "type"
```

What is important here, is that it is `interpret` and not `cast`.

We can see the difference in this example:

```
float a = 0.5;
int b = (int)a;
int c = *(int*)&a;

printf("%f %08x %08x\n", a, b, c);

// Output:
// 0.500000 00000000 3f000000
// 3f000000 is the way 0.5 is encoding following standard IEEE 754
```

It's usefull if you want to work on representation of floats for example:

```
float a = 1.5;
int b = *(int*)&a;
b &= 0xF;
a = *(float*)&b;
```

For example it's the reason of the use of this syntax here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_inverse_square_root#Overview_of_the_code, for manipulating bit of representation of double.

Comment: I didn't DV (yet), but your third comment should read "dereference the pointer"; and it is a cast. I see what you're trying to say but it isn't expressed very well.

Comment: Thanks I try to do it more clear. I use "interpret" word to emphaze the fact that it's different to cast a pointer and to cast a value.

Comment: Cool, I'll keep that in mind. I got very little experience in C so any tip if much appreciated.

Comment: **Note:** This answer fails to mention that, few exceptions aside, type punning by dereferencing pointer of invalid type breaks *strict aliasing rules* which results in *undefined behaviour*. To put it shortly, code is not standard compliant C, and thus should be avoided at all costs.